# left join, return non matching rows, where clause on right table, group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry about the complicated title.

I have two tables, customers and orders:

customers - names may be duplicated, ids are unique:

```
name | cid
 a   |  1
 a   |  2
 b   |  3
 b   |  4
 c   |  5
```

orders - pid is unique, join on cid:

```
pid | cid | date
 1  |  1  | 01/01/2012
 2  |  1  | 01/01/2012
 3  |  2  | 01/01/2012
 4  |  3  | 01/01/2012
 5  |  3  | 01/01/2012
 6  |  3  | 01/01/2012
```

So I used this code to get a count:

```
select customers.name, orders.date, count(*) as count
from customers
left JOIN orders ON customers.cid = orders.cid
where date between '01/01/2012' and '02/02/2012'
group by name,date
```

which worked fine but didnt give me null rows when the cid of customers didnt match a cid in orders, e.g. name-c, id-5

```
select customers.name, orders.date, count(*) as count
from customers
left JOIN orders ON customers.cid = orders.cid
AND date between '01/01/2012' and '02/02/2012'
group by name,date
```

So I changed the where to apply to the join instead, which works fine, it gives me the null rows.
So in this example I would get:

```
name | date       | count
 a   | 01/01/2012 | 3
 b   | null       | 1
 b   | 01/01/2012 | 3
 c   | null       | 1
```

But because names have different cid's it is giving me a null row even if the name itself does have rows in orders, which I don't want.

So I'm looking for a way for the null rows to only be returned when any other cid's that share the same name also do not have any rows in orders.

Thanks for any help.

---EDIT---

I have edited the counts for null rows, count never returns null but 1.

The result of

```
select * from (select customers.name, orders.date, count(*) as count
from customers
left JOIN orders ON customers.cid = orders.cid
AND date between '01/01/2012' and '02/02/2012'
group by name,date) as t1 group by name
```

is

```
name | date       | count
 a   | 01/01/2012 | 3
 b   | null       | 1
 c   | null       | 1
```

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of is to put your query into a subquery and group the super-query by name

Comment: @knittl i tried 
select * from (select customers.name, orders.date, count(*) as count
from customers
left JOIN orders ON customers.cid = orders.cid
AND date between '01/01/2012' and '02/02/2012'
group by name,date) as t1 group by name
but that just merges everything into the first date it has, did you mean something else?

Comment: that's what I meant, but you are right, it does not work as expected.

Comment: so in your example above, what will it return?

Comment: @JohnWoo I have added an edit to the bottom of my question with the result

Comment: @mrmryb: Shouldn't `b` have the date 01/01/2012 instead of null?

Comment: @João Nope, seems like it doesn't matter which cid returns the null row but it always comes before the non null ones, and then when the group by is applied it will go to the null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, select your date grouped by `(name, date)`, excluding `NULL`s, then join with a set of distinct names:

```
SELECT names.name, grouped.date, grouped.count
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT name FROM customers ) as names
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT customers.name, orders.date, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM customers
  LEFT JOIN orders ON customers.cid = orders.cid
  WHERE date BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '02/02/2012'
  GROUP BY name,date
) grouped
ON names.name = grouped.name
```

Comment: hey, query works great just rename grouped to sub and `SELECT sub.name` to `SELECT names.name`, here is the sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d4f5/1/0

Comment: works perfect, thank you, but I did have to add `order by name,date` on to the end, bit confused as to why the version on sqlfiddle doesn't need that

Comment: Sets are unordered by default, there is no defined order in which results are returned.

Comment: my mistake, I assumed that the sqlfiddle was being ordered but it was just because of the order customers were being inserted, entering customer name b into the table first yielded a similarly 'unordered' list

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be Group them together based on Cid's and then other parameters.
So you would get the proper output with NULL values based on Left Outer Join.